# how to fix CardView Corner radius issue?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm using below code to create a `CardView` with corners but it stay rectangular

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardview_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp">
```

**UPDATE :** there was a mistake in my Manifest i just remove this line:

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"

Comment: try to remove android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

Comment: the same thing.

Comment: Your code works for me. Issue is something else.

Comment: You should post your whole layout for better understanding

Comment: Are you runing in api <21 ?

Comment: no ,i'm trying on api 25

Comment: add card_view:cardCornerRadius="15dp" in cardview tag then clean and rebuild your project

Answer (score 7):

I also had same issue. The issue I found is...

```
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
```

removed this line from manifests and the issue resolved for me.

Answer (score 3):

I saw nothing wrong with your code, but if it couldn't worked. try to add this:

```
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/margin_small"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/margin_small"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

It worked well for me. And make sure you're runing above API 21.

Comment: Can you please mention changes to be made in layout ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

 </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

reference link : [check here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView)

Comment: Please, can you mention screenshot of your cardview screen

Answer (score -2):

try it into style.xml

`<item name="cardCornerRadius">9dp</item>`

or simply put this line in your card view XML

`app:cardCornerRadius="9dp"`